# How to read hive partitioned table via pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

New to spark programming and had a doubt regarding the method to read partitioned tables using pyspark.

Let us say we have a table partitioned as below:

`~/$table_name/category=$category/year=$year/month=$month/day=$day`

Now, I want to read data from all the categories, but want to restrict data by time period. Is there any way to specify this with wild cards rather than writing out all the individual paths?

Something to the effect of

```
table_path = ["~/$table_name/category=*/year=2019/month=03",
                         "~/$table_name/category=*/year=2019/month=04"]

table_df_raw = spark.read.option(
    "basePath", "~/$table_name").parquet(*table_path)
```

Also, as bonus is there a more pythonic way to specify the time ranges which may fall in different years rather than listing the paths individually.

Edit: To clarify a few things, I don't have access to the hive metastore for this table and hence can't access with just a SQL query. Also, the size of the data doesn't allow filtering post conversion to dataframe.

Comment: you say there is already a partitioned table..why don't you use methods like `select` and `filter` on the table read as a data frame? you don't have to worry about reading the underlying files.

Comment: Should have been clearer, I don't have access to the hive metastore for this particular data set and loading the entire table and then applying filters won't be feasible because of size of data. Kindly let me know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Wildcards can also be used to specify a range of days:

```py
table_df_raw = spark.read
                    .option("basePath", "~/$table_name")
                    .parquet("~/$table_name/category=*/year=2019/month={3,4,8}")
```

Or

```py
table_df_raw = spark.read
                    .option("basePath", "~/$table_name")
                    .parquet("~/$table_name/category=*/year=2019/month=[3-4]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Hortonworks HDP cluster? If yes, try to use HiveWarehouse connector. Its allow Spark to access Hive catalog. After this, you can perform any Spark SQL command over hive tables: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/223626/integrating-apache-hive-with-apache-spark-hive-war.html

If you aren't using Hortonworks, i suggest you look at this link: https://acadgild.com/blog/how-to-access-hive-tables-to-spark-sql

Comment: I mentioned that I don't have access to the hive metastore hence can't write plan ol' SQL

Comment: What happened to your hive metastore? You don't have permission to access it? About what you said before, you need to filter before convert your data to Dataframe?